# Can I pause halfway through coking boneless shoulder?

Tags: meat, cooking-time

My other half put the shoulder in the oven to cook so that when I got home I could finish it, but my food delivery hasn't come. Can I pause the cooking and go get the stuff that I need and then carry on cooking as normal? Bearing in mind that it will take me 45 minutes to come back from a shop.

Comment: Is this a pork shoulder? How long has it been in, and are you roasting or braising? The answer is probably no, but it's kind of critical to know what you've got in, how you're cooking it, and how long it's been in for us to help.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.

In your situation, as you're just trying to slow things down and not halt it entirely, you can turn the heat down as low as it'll go on your oven, and then when you get back, turn it back to the desired temperature.

It'll throw off the cooking time enough that you'll want to use a thermometer to check for done-ness.  (and it might finish in the time that the oven was set to low).

Comment: Yes — turning down the oven is the best thing to do. Meats like this cook much better when slow roasted too!

Comment: Turning down the oven will create an OK meat result, but the situation sounds like the OP is likely to be alone at home. I wouldn't leave an oven unattended for 45 min, even when turned at low.